# Trying to read a positive value in c

Tags: c

i just want to make sure that i read a positive value for x not sure whats wrong here

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    unsigned x;
    int i;
    do {
        printf("donner un nombre\n");
        scanf("%u", &x);
    } while (x <= 1);
    /*
    for (i = 0; i++; i < x) {
        int prime = 0;
        int x = 2;
        do {
            if (i % x == 0 ) {
                prime = 1;
            }
            x++;
        } while (prime == 0 && x < i);
        
        if (prime == 0) {
            printf("%i",i);
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: What's not working?  Since you don't really do anything with the number `x` that you read, it's probably hard to be sure.

Comment: It is always a good idea to check the return value of `scanf`.  Unless it returns 1, that means it couldn't read a number at all (like maybe if the user typed a letter instead).

Comment: even if i give a negative number the program doesn't ask me again

Comment: its seems when i give the number 0 it works but when i give a negative number it doesn't

Comment: `x` cannot be negative because its type is `unsigned`. The condition `x <= 1` only holds when `x == 0` or `x == 1`.

Comment: I suggest changing `x` to `int x` and `%u` in the `scanf` call to `%d`.  And definitely check `scanf's` return value, as I mentioned earlier.  If you say `if(scanf(...) != 1) { printf("bad input\n"); exit(1); }`, you'll see what was happening when you entered negative numbers before — that minus side was as unacceptable to `%u` as a letter like `"x"` would have been.

Comment: But if your next question is, "After `scanf` returns other than 1, what if I don't want to exit, what if I want to prompt the user to try again?", it turns out that's a harder problem, without a nice, easy answer.  The problem is basically that `scanf` is not designed for input situations like this, where the user might type something wrong.

Comment: ok thanks i changed it int and %d

Comment: by the way i have another question i changed the variable type to int but i kept the same call  %u . it worked without changing it to %d

Comment: why is that ? won't i have to change the call from %u to %d for it to work ? because it did anyways

Comment: `%u` requires a pointer to `unsigned int`. If you provide something else, the behaviour is *undefined*. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/1hTj3vqT6). It is recommended to use these compiler flags.

Comment: Note that the `for` loop in your commented-out code has the 2nd and 3rd statements round the wrong way: `for (i = 0; i++; i < x) {` should be `for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {`. The test condition is the second (middle) statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Unsigned is bad choice

First at all you change `unsigned` type to integer `int`, that alloved you to scan negative numbers such as -1, -5,...

### Wrong condition in loop

Also there is bug in `do while` loop, where you scan until the `x <= 1` but number 1 is positive number, so you have to change it to `x < 1`

**Final code will looks like this:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;
    do {
        printf("donner un nombre\n");
        scanf("%u", &x);
    } while (x < 1);

    // your code working with positive x

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention checking the return value from `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

Reading input, especially when it involves a numeric conversion is something done time and time again. It's worth taking the time to understand how to do it properly.

For starters, using `scanf()` for user-input can be done, but it is so full of pitfalls for the new C programmer that it is highly discouraged. This is due to the state that `scanf()` leaves your input buffer in both after good input (with potential additional characters and the `'\n'` left unread), and after invalid input (where all characters from the point of *matching-failure* forward are left unread). To avoid all of these pitfalls, simply read all input into a sufficiently sized buffer (character array) with `fgets()` and then convert the contents of the array as needed.

Why `fgets()` and a sufficiently sized buffer? `fgets()` reads an entire line of input (including the trialing `'\n'` produced by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> ensuring the input buffer (`stdin` in your case) is left in a proper state for your next read.

To convert the contents of the array to an integer value, `strtol()` provides the most robust diagnostics and error reporting in the event the user failed to enter a valid integer, but using `sscanf()` for the conversion at least provides a valid success/failed indication through its return.

(you couldn't have used `scanf()` correctly to begin with without ***checking the return***)

**How To Read User Input?**

The approach is simple, and it virtually the same for any input needed. You simply:

- loop continually prompting for input until a valid input is provided by the user (your read-loop),
- read the user input into a sufficiently sized buffer (don't skimp on buffer size),
- check if the user canceled input by generating a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows),
- attempt conversion of the contents of your buffer as needed (to `int` in your case) *checking the return* of the conversion function used,
- if the input is valid, check against any other constraints you have (positive `int` in your case)
- if all conditions for good input met -- break out of the read-loop, otherwise,
- handle the invalid input, and loop again.

No matter what you need to get from the user, you can use this approach. It's something you use so often, it makes sense to put it in a function you can call any time you need that type of input. For an `int` value, where you can provide an optional prompt to the user to be displayed, you can do something similar to:

```c
...

#define MAXC 256    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

/* read integer value from 'fp', update value at 'val' address.
 * returns 1 on success, 0 if user cancels input with ctrl+d (or
 * ctrl+z on windows)
 */
int read_int (int *val, FILE *fp, const char *prompt)
{
  char buf[MAXC];   /* buffer (char array) to hold line of input */
  
  for (;;) {        /* loop continually until valid input or user cancels */
    
    if (prompt) {                         /* if prompt not NULL, display */
      fputs (prompt, stdout);
    }
    
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {         /* read/validate line of input */
      puts ("(user canceled input)");
      return 0;
    }
    
    /* attempt conversion to int validating return/handle error */
    if (sscanf (buf, "%d", val) != 1) {
      fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
    }
    else {        /* otherwise, valid int received */
      break;      /* break input loop */
    }
  }
  
  return 1;       /* return success */
}
```

The function above will require the user to enter a valid integer, looping displaying the `prompt` and handling any input errors until the user does while still allowing the user to cancel input with a manual `EOF`. What it doesn't do is apply your constraint of requiring a positive value. This you add as an additional requirement where you call `read_int()` in your code.

For example, in `main()`<sup>1</sup> since you need a positive value, you simply call the `read_int()` function in another continual loop until a positive value is returned (handling the manual `EOF` case as well). That can look like the following:

```c
int main (void) {   /* proper invocation of main unless on freestanding sys */
  
  int x = 0;
  
  for (;;) {   /* loop continually prompting for input until x positive */
    /* validate return of read_int() checking if user canceled */
    if (read_int (&x, stdin, "donner un nombre: ") == 0) {
      return 0;     /* graceful exit on cancel -- not an error */
    }
    if (x > 0) {    /* test x in acceptable range (positive) */
      break;        /* break read loop */
    }
    /* handle x outside of range */
    fputs ("  error: invalid input, must be postive integer.\n", stderr);
  }
  
  printf ("\npostivie x: %d\n", x);
}
```

(**note:** above you simply apply a continual loop again, looping until the `int` value is in the range of positive integers -- handle the `0` case however you want to consider it)

If you need to cover the entire range of `unsigned`, then change the function to be `read_long()` (and change the types appropriately). Then in `main()` you can `#include <limits.h>` and test `if (0 < x && x <= UINT_MAX)` for input in range.

Putting it altogether simply requires adding `#include <stdio.h>` at the top, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 256    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

/* read integer value from 'fp', update value at 'val' address.
 * returns 1 on success, 0 if user cancels input with ctrl+d (or
 * ctrl+z on windows)
 */
int read_int (int *val, FILE *fp, const char *prompt)
{
  char buf[MAXC];   /* buffer (char array) to hold line of input */
  
  for (;;) {        /* loop continually until valid input or user cancels */
    
    if (prompt) {                         /* if prompt not NULL, display */
      fputs (prompt, stdout);
    }
    
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {         /* read/validate line of input */
      puts ("(user canceled input)");
      return 0;
    }
    
    /* attempt conversion to int validating return/handle error */
    if (sscanf (buf, "%d", val) != 1) {
      fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
    }
    else {        /* otherwise, valid int received */
      break;      /* break input loop */
    }
  }
  
  return 1;       /* return success */
}


int main (void) {   /* proper invocation of main unless on freestanding sys */
  
  int x = 0;
  
  for (;;) {   /* loop continually prompting for input until x positive */
    /* validate return of read_int() checking if user canceled */
    if (read_int (&x, stdin, "donner un nombre: ") == 0) {
      return 0;     /* graceful exit on cancel -- not an error */
    }
    if (x > 0) {    /* test x in acceptable range (positive) */
      break;        /* break read loop */
    }
    /* handle x outside of range */
    fputs ("  error: invalid input, must be postive integer.\n", stderr);
  }
  
  printf ("\npostivie x: %d\n", x);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Now that you have written your input routine -- go try and break it, every way you can think of -- and make sure it handles all cases correctly. Then there will always be one or two corner-cases you didn't think about you will have to fix later.

Does the input routine work, requiring a positive value?

```
$ ./bin/read_int_function
donner un nombre: 0
  error: invalid input, must be postive integer.
donner un nombre: banannas and pickles
  error: invalid integer input.
donner un nombre: ten
  error: invalid integer input.
donner un nombre: 10

postivie x: 10
```

What about handling the user canceling input?

```
$ ./bin/read_int_function
donner un nombre: foo
  error: invalid integer input.
donner un nombre: (user canceled input)
```

Handling user-input is one area that gives new C programmers no end of grief. Best to take the time and think through it now, learning how to correctly approach it. Doing so will save you a great deal of time and frustration.

Let me know if you have further questions.

---

**Footnotes:**

**1.)** Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  *See*: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). *See also*: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)  In a freestanding environment, the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined. *See*: [5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Linux as a development environment, you can take a look at `man 3 scanf`. This will give you the function's documentation.

That being said, the function returns a number which indicates how many valid inputs were read.

Knowing that, you can read a positive integer with the following code to check for read status:

```c
int rc;
unsigned int x;

rc = scanf("%u", &x);
if (rc == 1) {
    // valid input data
}
```