# How do I make the value of integer underflow to zero instead of it wrapping around?

Tags: c, underflow

I want to make sure that the user inputs unsigned integers. Is it possible to implement a simple solution so that when the user inputs negative values, it will always return zero instead of it wrapping around like how integer underflows work?

Comment: Input to a string and check for a minus sign.

Comment: `if(x < 0) x = 0;`

Comment: I  was suprised to find that a negative value entered for format spec `%u` is *not* rejected. Both MSVC and Godbolt accept the minus sign and report a successful conversion.

Comment: In C's input model, you can't prevent the user from typing something wrong, you can only react to it.  So, paradoxically, if you want the user to enter a nonnegative number, the easiest thing to do is input a *signed* `int`, and then if it's less than 0, do something.  So if you're using `scanf`, you actually want `%d`, not `%u`.

Comment: ...and if you want the full unsigned range, input to a larger signed type and check the value before assigning to the desired type.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Trying to read a positive value in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73998500).

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks a lot. I am a beginner and I thought I'd have to use another crazy function or feature as per conventions that I'm not yet aware of.

Comment: @WeatherVane [Every one of C's numeric `*scanf()` conversion specifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12) "Matches an optionally signed ..."

Comment: @AndrewHenle presumably then it acts in the same way as, say `unsigned num = -1;`

Comment: @WeatherVane `%u` is described as "whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtoul function with the value 10 for the base argument".  The [`strtoul()` description is several hundred words long](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4).  It's too early on a weekend morning for me to even try parsing that.

Comment: But within those [several hundred words](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4) @AndrewHenle refers to are indeed these eight: "optionally preceded by a plus or minus sign".